# Is There A Way To Call A Python3 Function From PHP 7.4.7?

Tags: python, php, function, server

I have a PHP file in my server, and I want it to be able to call Python function from another file. In the Python file, I want to write some information into a text file (.txt). When I run the Python file on its own, it works, and the text file contains the content that I told it to have. But, when I try to call the Python file from my PHP file, it does not work. In addition, I am using a Microsoft Window's Operating System, but I accept answers for Linux (preferably Ubuntu/Debian) as that is where I am running my web server. But, in the end, what I want to be able to do is this:

PHP:

```
<?php
// Call helloWorld() from Test.py
?>
```

And my python:

```
def helloWorld():
    print("Hello World!")

helloWorld() # Calls the above function
```

I have tried:

```
exec('python Test.py')  // The files are in the same directory
```

```
shell_exec('python Test.py') // The files are in the same directory
```

If possible, although not necessary, it would be nice to have the actual PHP script, rather than just "try shell_exec()". Again, that is not mandatory.

Thank you in advance, and any help is appreciated.

Comment: What happened when you tried those two things?

Comment: @mkrieger1 The Python did not execute when I tried them. No file was made. But, again, when I just debugged (I think that's the right workd) the Python file on it's own, it worked. So, therefore, I know that the PHP is not the problem and nor is the Python file. But rather the problem originates from the way that the PHP is linked with the Python file. So that is what I am asking, how do I do that, and why are the recommended ways not working? Thanks!

Comment: What file did you expect to be created?

Comment: If you run this Python code as a script, it will not have any output. Only a function `helloWorld` is defined, but it is never called.

Comment: @mkrieger1 So, how do I call a function from PHP, then?

Comment: You don’t call it from PHP, you need to call it inside the Python script which you run from PHP.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Thank you. This now brings me back to my original question. I will soon make an edit. So, all I need to know now is just how to call a python SCRIPT using PHP. Then the script will do the function, if I call the function within the script. Thanks, and I hope to get an answer soon.

Comment: I think the code you have shown *does* call the script. It just didn’t produce any output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215766/discussion-between-jason-dsilva-and-mkrieger1). I didn't send this, the StackOverflow system sent it, because there were too many comments on my post...

Comment: Anyways, in my real Python Script, and I'll give a link to it soon, I have a Python file that will create/open, write, and close another Text (.txt) file. Then I should be able to see that file. If I try to call the script from PHP, it doesn't work. But when I run the Python by itself (without using PHP), it works. Therefore, I know there is a problem with the PHP connection to the Python. My question is, how do I fix it?

Comment: In order to be able to answer that, you need to create a [mre].